# What does the 'd' mean in ls -al results and what is that slot called?

Tags: permissions, files, ls

In Linux, what does the `d` mean in the first position of `drwxr-xr-x`?  And what are all of the possible letters that could be there, and what do they mean?

I'm trying to learn more about the Linux file permissions system, and I'd like to see a list of the character meanings for the first slot.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It means that it is a directory. The first mode field is the "special file" designator; regular files display as `-` (none). As for which possible letters could be there, on Linux the following exist:

- `d` (directory)
- `c` (character device)
- `l` (symlink)
- `p` (named pipe)
- `s` (socket)
- `b` (block device)
- `D` (door, not common on Linux systems, but has been ported)

Comment: This wasn't in the man page. Is there any "standard" approach for finding this info?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it in `info ls`.

Answer (score 10):

**On Gentoo, what the first character in a linux file permissions drwxrwxrwx means:**

The first character gives you a hint of the type of object it is.

Possible values for that first character: ( `-`, `d`, `c`, `l`, `p`, `s`, `b`, `D` )

**- (dash) means file and and d means directory.**

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ mkdir my_empty_directory
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ touch myfile.txt
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 el users 4096 Dec 21 13:06 .
drwx--x--x 9 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:54 my_empty_directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 el users  182 Dec 21 11:45 myfile.txt
```

`my_empty_directory` has a 'd' and is a directory, and `myfile.txt` has a '-' and is a normal text file.

**c means character device file**

```
el@angeliqe /dev $ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root      4080 Dec 19 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      4096 Nov  3 19:00 ..
crw-rw----  1 root tty     7, 133 Nov 24 10:13 vcsa5
```

vcsa5 is a character device file.  Find character device files with this command: `find / -type c -print 2>/dev/null`

**b means block device**

```
el@angeliqe /dev $ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root      4080 Dec 19 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      4096 Nov  3 19:00 ..
brw-rw----  1 root disk    8,   0 Nov 24 10:13 sda
```

sda is a block device.  Find block device files with this command: `find / -type b -print 2>/dev/null`

**l means link**

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ touch myfile.txt
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ ln -s myfile.txt myfile2.txt
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4096 Dec 21 13:23 .
drwx--x--x 9 el users 4096 Dec 21 13:22 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 el users    0 Dec 21 13:23 myfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 el users   10 Dec 21 13:23 myfile2.txt -> myfile.txt
```

`myfile2.txt` is a symbolic link to `myfile.txt`.  Find symbolic link files with this command: `find / -type l -print 2>/dev/null`

**p means named pipe**

```
el@angeliqe /dev $ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root      4080 Dec 19 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      4096 Nov  3 19:00 ..
prw-------  1 root root         0 Nov 24 10:13 initctl
```

initctl is a named pipe.  Find pipe files with this command: `find / -type p -print 2>/dev/null`

**s is a socket**

```
el@angeliqe /dev $ ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root      4080 Dec 19 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      4096 Nov  3 19:00 ..
srwxrwxrwx  1 root root         0 Nov 24 10:13 gpmctl
```

gpmctl is a socket.  Find socket files with this command: `find / -type s -print 2>/dev/null`

**D means door**

None found on my Gentoo.